# Selector not working with TabLayout

Tags: android

I have added tab layout with my custom view as below

java code

```
     for (int i = 0; i < allTabs.getTabCount(); i++) {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = allTabs.getTabAt(i);
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, allTabs, false);
        tvTabText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tab_title);
        View view = (View) v.findViewById(R.id.deviderView);
        tvTabText.setText(tab.getText());
        tab.setCustomView(v);
        if (i == 0) {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE); // Hide last devider


        }
    }
```

Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<!-- Tab title -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tab_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="sdasd"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@drawable/tab_item_selector"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal" />

<!-- Tab divider -->

<View
    android:id="@+id/deviderView"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="right" />
```

tab_item_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
<item android:color="#82c6e6" />
```

i have seted first tab selected

```
allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("CURRENT YEAR"),true);
```

also try with

```
if (i == 0) {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tab.select();
        }
```

in custom view.

i also try

```
allTabs.setTabTextColors(normal,selected);
```

this is my TabLayout

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/master_color"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
    app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"/>

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
```

once view appear i click on forst tab than tab will show wihte color text but when i releas press then after text going to normal color every time. 
if i click on second tab and then click on first tab it will work fine as a aspect.

all time load first tab but i cant get first tab with selected(means as i want with white color text when tab is select)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in your tabLayout:

```
app:tabTextColor="@color/gray"
app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
```

Comment: yes it will work but i am using custom layout, and in custom layout this properties not working. i have set devider between two tab.